# memory limit in hhvm

Tags: php, memory-limit, hhvm

I have a setup with Directadmin, nginx and hhvm. I want to set memory_limit for every user through custom config files for hhvm. right now every user has a config file in the following directory.

```
/usr/local/directadmin/users/user/hhvm.ini
```

The memory_limit is set to me 128M, but when I check it through a php file with

```
echo ini_get("memory_limit");
```

I get the following output.

```
9223372036854775807
```

I have no idea where that number comes from. I do know that it is the biggest integer known for 64-bit systems. So how can i get the output to be 128M?

Comment: do `phpinfo()`. it'll tell you what .ini files are being loaded. and remember that php can be overriden at the .htaccess/httpd.conf levels as well, which take effect AFTER php.ini files are parsed.

Comment: I know what ini files are loaded. Both say    memory_limit = 128M, but I still get    9223372036854775807 as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was pretty stupid actually.

After an update the output from the memory_limit was what I set it to.
So in short it was a bug in hhvm.